# Make DUMB Fails on Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, makefile, allegro, allegro5

I am trying to install DUMB to be able to install allegro 5 on Mac OS X 10.8. I downloaded the source files and when I type `make` I get an error. Below is the whole thing I get when I type `make`.

I couldn't fit the whole text of error, so here it is on pastebin http://pastebin.com/pnhukMQ6

Reading through it, I think the errors have something to do with pointers, and deprecated stuff, I didn't understand much of it. Did anybody try to install it and worked, or encountered the same error and can help me.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to build DUMB's Allegro 4 programs. You should answer `N` to wanting Allegro support when building DUMB because they won't work with Allegro 5.

Instead, Allegro 5 has built-in support for DUMB. You just need to build DUMB's common library and make sure it's in a place that Allegro 5 will see when you run its `cmake`.